Why we compute expectation value of an operator?
I'm new in quantum mechanics. J.J.Sakurai in his book in chapter 1 defines the expectation value of an oeprator $A$ taken with respect to state $|\alpha \rangle $ as $\langle A\rangle \equiv \langle \alpha |A|\alpha \rangle$. I am really grateful if someone could tell me why we need to compute expectation value of an operator?

Because it tells what (average) result we would get when we make a measurement. Or were you asking something more complicated that I have missed?

Dear @JohnRennie Thank you so much for the comment. In fact, I meant why in QFT or CFT we compute the expection value of two operators like $\langle X(z)X(w)\rangle$? What does it tell us? Why is it important?

In Quantum Mechanics, every state corresponds to a different set of probabilities for the possible measurements of an observable represented by an operator on the Hilbert space of the states. By repeating many measurements on systems prepared in the same state, every possible observable value should appear with a frequency close to its probability.
The average of all those values, weighted with the corresponding probabilities, is the expected average after many measurements.
Indeed, every operator can be represented by a sum of all the projectors over its eigenstates multiplied by the corresponding eigenvalues
$$
\hat A = \sum_{\lambda} \lambda \hat P_{\lambda}.
$$
Moreover, the eigenstates of a self-adjoint operator are a basis of the Hilbert space. Therefore, every state can be decomposed as
$$
\left| \alpha \right> = \sum_{\lambda} c_{\lambda} \left| \lambda \right>,
$$
with $\sum_{\lambda} |c_{\lambda}|^2 =1$ for normalized states.
Therefore,
$$
\langle \alpha| \hat A | \alpha \rangle = \sum_{\lambda}|c_{\lambda} |^2\lambda
$$
is precisely the average of all the possible values of the observable $A$, with weights equal to the corresponding probabilities.

not sure that different states correspond to different probabilities.  Different states will result in generally different probabilities, but to call this a correspondence is IMO a bit an abuse of the verb “to correspond”.

@ZeroTheHero I did not write that different states correspond to different probabilities. Still, each state has its probability, sometimes different for each state, some other times equal. This does not invalidate what I wrote. If you are puzzled by the word correspondence, its meaning, as in a mathematical relation, is nothing more than the possibility of pairing each state with a set of probabilities for every possible outcome of a measurement.

The key point is to accept that the physical observables don't have well defined values all the time, like classical physics. The Stern-Gerlach shows it: the spin components behave like random variables, for which we do not ask the value, since it can be one of many in a set. The better we can do with a random variable is to measure its moments, like average, standard deviation, etc. The Ehrenfest theorem show us that the averages of position and momentum recovers similar equations of motion than in Classical Physics, so we accept such averages as the best description of the system at a time.
For some applications of quantum theory, we don't need a average value but probabilities, like when studying transitions between some states. The procedure is similar, and we use the same formalism restructure for averages.
In resume: we calculate averages because it is everything we have access to.

Because it represents an average state system is in for a sufficiently large number of measurements.
I will fallback to the classical analog, since question sounds pretty much like Why do we need expectation values at all in Physics.
Imagine you play coin flipping game and you need to predict how coin will likely land,- heads or tails.
An expected value of coin flip is :
$$ E[\text{flip}] = 0.5~\text{heads} + 0.5~\text{tails} \tag 1$$
Now substitute numeric values $\text{heads}=1$ and $\text{tails}=0$ into (1) equation for extrapolating coin flipping average result :
$$ E[\text{flip}] = 0.5~\cdot 1 + 0.5 \cdot ~0 = 0.5 \tag 2 $$
It shows that an average state which you will encounter is neither heads nor tails, but "something in the middle" of those two. This single number encodes pretty much all information we need,- the fact that $50\%$ of times coin will land heads, and the other half $50\%$ cases,- tails. So by taking coin flipping "measurements" you have deduced that while coin is in the air,- it's state is in superposition like (1) describes. But you don't have the direct access to this superimposed state, just to the final result, which isn't something coin operates on.
Similarly, most quantum mechanical processes are probabilistic which you can only describe statistically.

In most textbooks that rule for calculating expectation values, the Born rule, is taken as a postulate of quantum theory without much explanation of the circumstances under which it applies. According to these textbooks the state collapses to whatever state you see with some probability but no explanation of how this happens is given.
There are theories that explicitly modify quantum theory to include collapse:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.14969
Those theories in general can't reproduce most successful experimental predictions of quantum theory:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00568
In quantum theory without such modifications in general the final state of a system in an experiment depends on what happens to all of the possible states during the experiment: this is called quantum interference. During interference in general the square amplitudes of states that gives the probabilities in the expectation value above do not obey the rules of probability. For an example, see Section 2 of this paper:
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911150
When information is copied out of a quantum system interference is suppressed:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
Contrary to some of the posts above it well known in the literature that Ehrenfest's theorem is not sufficient to suppress interference in general:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.13717
There are some explanations of the Born rule in quantum theory without collapse modifications that use decision theory or invariance of the state to explain probabilities:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0405161
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906015
https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.02048
https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.2718

Quantum mechanics is a statistical theory at the foundational level, meaning measuring a quantity (an observable) $A$ on two systems identical in every way, with the initial conditions etc, may produce different outcomes.  The various outcomes each have some probability so the natural thing to do is to produce a probability distribution of the outcomes of the measurement of $A$ for systems in that state.  To understand the distribution, one usually computes averages (or expectation values), and various moments for the distribution.  Hence the emphasis on average values and variances.
There is an important caveat.  If the system is prepared in an eigenstate of the observable, then you will get only one outcome, and this outcome will of course occur 100% of the time as it is the only possible outcome.
